# Range limites in ExtraObjects primitive_xyz_function_surface

Tags: python, mesh

I'm new to Blender (and even more so with Python).

I'm trying to create a mesh representing a laser gaussian beam using the `primitive_xyz_function_surface` function from the ExtraObjects add-on. **But I'm struggling with the range variables which seem to be limited to [-100,+100]**.

Here is an *essentials-only* to illustrate the problem.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

# create gaussian beam (micon scale)

lam = 0.488               # wavelenght
wo = 1                    # weist
n = 1.33                  # refraction index

min_x,max_x = -100,100    # limits

zR = ( np.pi * wo*wo * n) / lam            # just a compute state
w = f"{wo} * sqrt( 1 + ( u/{zR} )**2 )"    # function for primitive_xyz_function_surface

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface(
    x_eq="u", y_eq=f"({w})*cos(v)", z_eq=f"({w})*sin(v)",
    range_u_min=min_x, range_u_max=max_x, range_u_step=60, wrap_u=False, 
    range_v_min=0, range_v_max=2*np.pi, range_v_step=128, wrap_v=True,
    show_wire=False, edit_mode=False,
)
```

Here is an image of the resulting object :
[image: gaussian beam with primitive_xyz_function_surface]

So here, the variables `max_x` and `min_x` define the spread of the mesh in dimension x. And this works for values between [-100,100]. **But stops working for values above 100  and bellow -100!**

Is this a designed limitation ? If so, is there a way to overwrite it ?

I wasn't able to find anything on the web about this issue.
I use Blender 2.93.2 , with Python 3.9.6 , under ArchLinux .

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me ! :D

Answer (score 1):

**Use a scale factor.**

Without editing the addon to change the property min / max could simply remap the space, `u -> s * u` *eg* to  change the u range tenfold replace any  `u` with `10 * u`

Edit to add a scale factor `s` and replace `u` in equation with `s * u`.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

# create gaussian beam (micon scale)

lam = 0.488               # wavelenght
wo = 1                    # weist
n = 1.33                  # refraction index

s = 2 # scale factor
min_x,max_x = -100, 100    # limits

zR = ( np.pi * wo*wo * n) / lam            # just a compute state
w = f"{wo} * sqrt( 1 + ( {s} * u/{zR} )**2 )"    # function for primitive_xyz_function_surface

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface(
    x_eq=f"{s} * u", 
    y_eq=f"({w})*cos(v)", 
    z_eq=f"({w})*sin(v)",
    range_u_min=min_x, 
    range_u_max=max_x, 
    range_u_step=60, 
    wrap_u=False, 
    range_v_min=0, 
    range_v_max=2*np.pi, 
    range_v_step=128, 
    wrap_v=True,
    show_wire=False, 
    edit_mode=False,
)
```

Note this could also be done via one of the helper functions.